# Ocelot Administration API Gateway running in Docker container giving 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, containers, ocelot

I have a .Net 6 API Gateway application which has ocelot administration and when run on localhost:4000 it starts fine in the browser without issues and when the endpoint http://localhost:5000/administrator/connect/token is run on postman a jwt token is generated without any issues,now when i create a docker container with command "docker run -it --rm -p 4000:80 gatewayApp" it starts the container fine.now when i try to run the same endpoint on postman it gives a 500 internal server error,tried also changing the port to 8080 when creating a container but same error arrises,please see the ocelot config file below and error below,assistance will be appreciated

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownStreamPathTemplate": "/api/Weather{everything}",
      "DownStreamScheme": "https",
      "DownStreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "port": 44381
        }
      ],
      "UpStreamPathTemplate": "/api/Weather{everything}",
      "UpStreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ]
    }
]
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "AdministrationPath": "/administrator"
  }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", false, true);

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration).AddAdministration("/administrator","secret");

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

error

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]

      Connection id "0HMI31RLJST9K", Request id "0HMI31RLJST9K:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

      System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:5000/administrator/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

       ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://localhost:5000/administrator/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (localhost:5000)

       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address

         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)

         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.
```

Comment: change ocelot json downstream port to backend service docker port.

Comment: You can't use `localhost` inside the docker container. Use `host.docker.internal` instead.